# HttpClient on Xamarin.Form's Android platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing Xamarin.Forms app now. How do I call HttpClient (or other alternatives?) from Android project?

The class structure is such:

```
public class SomePCLClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DependencyServices<SomeClass>().GetFromEachPlatform();
    }
}

public class AndroidInterface : ISomeInterface
{
    public Result GetFromEachPlatform()
    {
        //Some platform-specific calculations here
        //And then I need to call some webAPI here
    }
}

public class UwpInterface : ISomeInterface
{
    public Result GetFromEachPlatform()
    {
        //Some platform-specific calculations here
        //I don't need call webAPI in UWP... for some reasons
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `HttpClient` directly in your PCL project or Android project.

Comment: You can use HttpClient in your PCL Project and refer in Project Android and call in method, not is necessary dependency injection for the HttpClient code.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes @SushiHangover is right. I can use HttpClient directly, it was just my VS and some of the dependencies got messed up, I couldn't get the HttpClient setup - for some unknown reasons. Fixed it by reinstalling most of the Nuget dependencies and deleting the bin/obj folder. Really wasted my times zzz